# Populating only specific fields in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a document like this:

Info collection:

```
{
  infoType: "Appointment",
  contact: ObjectId("5baa28a3f1268917e9220138"),
}
```

Contact collection:

```
{
  name: "ABC",
  email: "abc@def.com"
}
```

And I want to populate only contact name in query by using populate method in mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will might help you to get exactly what you want.

```
infoModel.find({contactId: ObjectId("5baa28a3f1268917e9220138")})
.populate('contact', "name email")
.then(infoDetails => {
    console.log("Info Details -> ", infoDetails)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error Occured -> ", err)
})
```

Refer [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for further knowledge.