# How to query document that has array of multiple reference in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

I have a collection called 'assignments' that is like below:

```
  [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60e1d5824a5b1c32c069c864"),
        "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
        "students" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60e1d5824a5b1c32c069c865"),
                "user" : ObjectId("601e489fb77a9fabf85ea306"),
                "section" : ObjectId("6002fae3e58bc750b4394229")
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60e1d5824a5b1c32c069c866"),
                "user" : ObjectId("601e48cdb77a9fabf85ea307"),
                "section" : ObjectId("6002fae3e58bc750b4394229")
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60e1c8a6a2886142b8b86523"),
        "students" : [
        ],
        "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
        
    }]
```

Here you see an array named "students". I want to get details of "user" and "section" while querying the "assignments".

I am using graphql. And 'students' is a field of the type 'Assignment' like below:

```
type AssignmentStudent{
    user:User
    section:Section
}

type Assignment{
    id:ID!
    createdAt:Date
    updatedAt:Date
    course:Course!
    students:[AssignmentStudent!]
}
```

When I query I get information of 'course', but for 'students' I am not sure what to do.

In 'Assignment' resolver I have written query for 'course' like this:

```
Assignment: {
        async course(parent, { input }, context, info) {
            try {
                return await Course.findById(parent.course)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('err', err.message);
            }
        }
}
```

For actual result of 'stuents' what should I do ?

Comment: Please show whatever you tried and the problem that you are facing.

Comment: I have updated my question. would you please check it now?

Answer (score 1):

I saw you already found a solution that works for you, however another method is to use mongoose's populate, as you can specify specifically what you want it to return.

```
Assignment: {
  async course(parent, {
    input
  }, context, info) {
    try {
      return await Course.findById(parent.course).populate('students', 'user section') 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err', err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're already storing them as ObjectIds (with reference I assume), populate will populate the field you specify, in this case students - and the second argument added will further specify what to return from it. If you have issues with populate even tho your code is correct, sometimes adding `.execPopulate()` at the end of it will do the trick (can't explain this one).

Some other questions/articles on populating in mongoose (and specifiying fields):

- [Populating only specific fields in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589758/populating-only-specific-fields-in-mongoose)
- [Populate nested Object in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289537/mongodb-populate-nested-object-in-array)
- [Mongoosejs.com article on populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)
- [Article from medium](https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to traverse students array and for every item make similar findOne. Or you can filter ids and make find({ _id: { $in: ['1', '2', '3'] } }), and then attach result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I went for an approach like below which worked for me. I am not sure whether this approach is efficient or not, but it worked.

```
async students(parent, { input }, context, info) {
            try {

                const promises = parent.students.map(async (item) => {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        user: await User.findById(item.user),
                        section: await Section.findById(item.section)
                    }
                });
                return Promise.all(promises);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('err', err.message);
            }
        },
```